# Question about Modules over PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, principal-ideal-domains

While reading about modules over PIDs, I saw the following example. Let $R$ be a PID and $I = Rx$. Factor the generator $x$ into prime element powers and a unit $u$ in $R$
$$x = u p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_t^{e_t}.$$
Then $R/I = R/(x)= R/(p_1^{e_1}) \oplus \dots\oplus R/(p_t^{e_t})$.

While I've seen a proof showing that for a general ring, if $I, J$ are ideals such that $I + J = 1$ then $R/IJ \cong R/I \oplus R/J$.

However, I've got a couple of questions with this. First off, to be able to say this, we need to know that $(p_1^{e_1}) +\dots+ (p_t^{e_t}) = R$. Why is this the case? Secondly, how is the two-ideal case extended to the $t$ ideals case?

Thank you for your clarifications!

Comment: Look for the keywords  "Chinese remainder theorem" and have a look at the proof.

Comment: I see, this is starting to help me put the pieces together. So is the idea that the sum of every pair of ideals equal to the whole ring? Why must this be true?

Comment: Bezout's identity tells us that any two coprime elements of a PID generate the unit ideal.

Comment: Exactly what has been said above, and use induction.

Comment: I think you should look at the proof and see where exactly you need that $I+J=1$. Then you can think by yourself what weaker statement you would have if this weren't the case. I think that the morphism from left to right is no longer surjective, but don't trust me ok? ;)